# WPF why is this binding not working?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Property in my viewmodel that I'm trying to bind to:

```
 private TextActionValue _textActionVal;
    public TextActionValue TextActionVal
    {
        get { return _textActionVal; }
        set
        {
            _textActionVal = value; 
        }
    }
```

xaml:

```
<Grid Margin="0,15,15,15" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0">
        <TextBox Margin="0,5,0,5" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Text="{Binding TextActionValue.Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="100"></TextBox>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

And finally the TextActionValue class:

```
public class TextActionValue : ISomeAction, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _text;
    public String Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The text property is filled.  There's definitely a value in there when I step it.

If I just bind to a basic string property it works.  It does not like "TextActionValue.Text".  This is not an option unless I do some refactoring which I want to avoid if I can.

If I put a breakpoint inside of TextActionValue get...the get is never hit.  So this is telling me the binding is never created.  Why though...or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Comment: Your property is called `TextActionVal`, but in your TextBox's Text property you are setting the binding to `TextActionValue`

Comment: Why in the world would someone down vote this question?  Who cares if it was a simple oversight.  You're talking a difference of two characters.

Comment: Because questions that only help one person are useless. (Learn to [debug data bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)...)

Comment: 50% of the questions on here are to "help one person"...the poster.

Comment: @user1631520: You cannot derive normative statements from descriptive ones. Read the close-reason description: `This question is unlikely to help any future visitors`. Those are the *rules*, everything else is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding to `TextActionVal.Text` instead of `TextActionValue.Text`

You are trying to bind to the class not the property.

Also check your output window while debugging to see data binding errors.

Comment: Good Lord...thank you!!!  I knew it was going to be a stupid stupid mistake.  I'll try and mark as answer if that's it (I'm sure it is)

Comment: That was it!  Answer marked.  Appreciate it.  (I have to wait 5 min's...but I'll accept it)